# AWS Lambda + SQS, processing whole queue at once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue that is continuously receiving messages. I also have NodeJS Lambda that is processing queue. Processing should happen periodically but fairly rarely, like twice a day. Lambda that is processing the queue is processing the content of the queue in a single batch and it is important that it can process full content of the queue when it starts the processing.

Getting a single message from the queue is simple. It is async operation and I can put that inside the promise and handle the message when the promise is resolved.

Now the problem is how do I process full queue? I should loop until the queue is empty, but since the operation is async I do not know when to end the loop. I can see few fairly ugly solutions for this. Like having some stop variable that I update in the callbacks of async operations and stop the loop when it's updated, but it does not sound like the ideal solution. I would need to put some read delay so that I don't bombard queue with unnecessary read operations.

What would be a solid solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/744983/aws-sqs-sns-lambda?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your issue, your Lambda is scheduled to run twice a day (or so), and when it runs you want it to process all messages sitting in an SQS queue.

You don't want to wait for messages but to directly consume existing messages in the SQS queue (+ your Lambda isn't allowed to run more than 300 s), so I would go for [short polling and not long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html#sqs-short-long-polling-differences), setting `WaitTimeSeconds=0`. You can then set `MaxNumberOfMessages=10` (maximum allowed), but since `receiveMessage` in short polling requests only a subset of all SQS hosts, you're not guaranteed to get all messages actually sitting in the queue with a single call (even if less than 10).

I would thus write code and keep trace of the number of consecutive calls to `receiveMessage` returning no message at all. If a new callback from `receiveMessage` returns any message, you reset this counter and start again. Once the number has reached a threshold of your choice (you may define it empirically, I would start around 10), your script considers that there is actually no message in the queue and exits.

You may help convenient methods to lighten the callback syntax, like `receiveMessages` [here](https://github.com/nielskrijger/sqs).